# Can I insert binary data into MySQL TEXT column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, binary-data

Is it possible to insert binary data into MySQL `TEXT` column? I have a table that I'd like to use for storing both UTF-8 text and binary data (very basic structure - `id int(11), type char(1), data text`), but when I try to insert some binary data (JPEG image) into the `data` column, the column is empty.

I use `mysql_query` and `mysql_real_escape_string` in PHP to execute the INSERT query, both of them should be binary safe. Example code:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(" . (int)$id . ", 'b', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($jpegImageData) . "')");
```

I don't want to change the `data` column type to `BLOB` - in some cases, I need to use to compare / collate strings in this column.

Comment: This really screams of bad database design

Comment: Maybe you have some mysql exceptions? `echo mysql_error($handle);`

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that your binary data might just as well be invalid UTF-8, which will lead to problems/errors when you try to have a string with broken encoding stored in the database as UTF-8? If you're curious for those errors, please do try and let me know the result! =]

Answer (score 1):

Why not? Just encode in base64 and put it into that field.

```
<?php
$str = 'Some UTF-8 string or even a binary array';
echo base64_encode($str);
?>
```

Comment: I mean, can I insert the binary data to text column without base64 encoding? Should it work or is this the reason why the column is empty?

Comment: To be honest, never did that but I believe you can, because their core difference is just how mysql treats them, not how they are stored (which depends purely on storage engine).